# cant get html of a url using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, woocommerce

I have a C# application which needs to call a WooCommerce API and read its HTML response. 
I use this code:

```
public static String code(string Url)
{

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";

    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();

    return result;
}
```

but I get this error on the selected line:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

I tried several ways but like every time I got the same error; these are some ways I tried to solve it:

```
myRequest .UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myRequest .PreAuthenticate = true;
myRequest .Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

or

```
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("UserName", "PassWord");
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; request.PreAuthenticate = true;
```

In addition, I should say that when I open my URL in the browser for the first time, Chrome shows me a security alert, but just for the first time.
Please help me, I really need to solve this.

Comment: hmm i advise you to try fiddler and look up whats going wrong with application

Comment: You need to find out how that server wants you to authenticate.

Comment: were you able to hit url in an usual way ?

Comment: @Rahul Agarwal  yes i am

Comment: @SLaks whenever i open url in browser it shows me the data , how can i find it out ?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are connecting to an HTTPS service with an invalid certificate (which you should ignore, since apparently you trust that service).

Here on StackOverflow there's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https), whose accepted answer I am including into your code:

```
public static String code(string Url)
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = 
        new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";

     WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();

    return result;
}

public bool AcceptAllCertifications(object sender, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certification, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```