# Check if a webpage is online using VB in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been toying with getting this working for a while now to no avail.

I want to check if a website is available and display its status in a label.  I have no code to share as I haven't got this anywhere close.  I am using VS 2013 building a asp.net website using VB.

I thought I could just ping the website but after multiple test using command.exe the website doesn't respond to pings even when up.

I know the page will be taken offline periodically for updates as this happened last week and when it is you get page cannot be displayed.  I need to test if the page is online and return true if it is and false if not.

Comment: Is it your website or a 3rd party's? If you have control over the site you could dump a small text file in the root with the status, means if it's down for maintenance etc. you could update this and read it from your app.

Comment: ping is an ICMP tool that *might* have told you if the server was switched on but would have given you no information about what services (except Ping) were running. Is it enough to check that a page is returned when trying to access the website? What if that page just contains the text "this service is not available"?

Comment: A lot of websites won't respond to ping so that's definitely not a reliable method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way is to do an `httpWebRequest` and examine the result.  If the page doesn't exist, you will get an error that indicates that.  I'm not as familiar with `.webClient` but that apparently works as well.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net) past question gives you examples of both.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using `HttpWebRequest`.

```
try {
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("siteAddress");
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
catch(WebException e) {
    //There is a problem accessing the site
}
```

Comment: Will a 404 return an error?  I don't believe so in which case this catch won't help.  You'll have to parse what the server returns.  Not hard to do though.

Comment: @nycdan, 404, would be an exception, caught in `WebException`