# How to execute a URL without running in webbrowser on button click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

After clicking a button in ASPX page I have to execute a URL

```
http://127.0.0.1/phptest/sendmail.php?id=+@USERNAME
```

using VB.net. `@USERNAME` comes from textbox.

Comment: You mean `redirect`?

Comment: no redirect is needed.if i am able to run that URL,a mail will be send

Comment: You say `vbscript`, why tag this `asp.net` and `vb.net`?

Comment: Please clarify what language you're using. What you said in the comments to my answer indicates that you're *not* using VBScript.

Comment: i have a web form named index.aspx.In that there is a button.Button click code is written in index.aspx.vb.When i run the project broser will open with a button.When i click the button it should run the URL and URL should not show in browser.I need a code for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTTP GET in VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 1):

Make an [HTTP request](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh453379.aspx) if you need to call a URL from VBScript:

```
username = ...
url = "http://127.0.0.1/phptest/sendmail.php?id=+@" & username

Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "GET", url, False
req.send

If req.status = 200 Then
  'request successful
Else
  'request failed
End If
```

Comment: what is the datatype of reg and url

Comment: Cannot create ActiveX component.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated

Comment: `req` is an XMLHTTPRequest object (IServerXMLHTTPRequest2 to be precise) and `url` is a string, obviously. I messed up the object name in the `CreateObject` statement, though. Fixed.

Comment: Dim url as String Dim req As ??

Comment: VBScript does not support [`Dim var As type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zexdsyc0%28v=vs.84%29).

Comment: my file name is test.aspx.vb

Comment: Then you're probably using VB6 or VB.net, not VBScript. Please do not lie about what language you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that in vbscript :

```
Dim URL,ws,USERNAME
USERNAME = InputBox("Type your USERNAME","USERNAME","USERNAME")
URL =  "http://127.0.0.1/phptest/sendmail.php?id=+@"& USERNAME &""
set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
ws.run URL
```

Comment: Thank you.Its working but opening that URl in web browser while running

Comment: I don't understand your aim ? can you please be more explicit ? this not what do you expect to do ?

Comment: i have a aspx web form .In that there is a button.If i click that button,it should run a url.No need to show or run the URL in webbrowser.

Comment: i have a web form named index.aspx.In that there is a button.Button click code is written in index.aspx.vb.When i run the project broser will open with a button.When i click the button it should run the URL and URL should not show in browser.I need a code for that