# How to get to the JSON text using the VBnet standard browser

Tags: json, browser, geocode

Sorry it is difficult to provide code for this.

In a normal browser (firefox, IE etc) when I enter a Google Geo Code API URL 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=&key=

with myAddress and mykey set correctly.  I get a the JSON response as text in the browser window.

I would like to do exactly the same with a VBNet browser control.  That is-

Set aBrowser.Navigate property to my Google GeoCode API URL and then receive the JSON back as text in the browser that can be accessed with aBrowser.document.... .

However, VBnet seems to immediately abort the url navigation task and invites the user via a dialogue box to save a file.  If I save the file and then inspect it, the content is the JSON text that I expected to see inside the browser document.

This is my first play with JSON and assumed that the VBNet browser would behave just like IE.  I am missing something?

Thanks in advance.
Geoff

Answer (score 0):

Had a play with the answer provided for for [HTTP GET in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net)

This  is easily adapted to work with Google GEO Code API and the JSON text is received into a string. I can then either process the string or place the string on the browser page.

This works for me.