# How to make VB.Net Sever program to open a web page

Tags: vb.net

I want to know how to create a server to open a webpage with IP and Port number using VB.Net.

A web page is stored in the local computer and it can create HTML or ASP.Net.

How to get the start for this? Is this VB.Net HTTP server or Socket programming?

Comment: check out this question to see if it answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92522/http-get-in-vb-net

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately _"please point me in the right direction"_-questions are off-topic here as they're too broad to answer. Questions should mainly focus on a single, _specific_ problem which can be addressed by a decent answer. There are lots of resources on the internet that will get you on your way. Please take a moment to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to familiarize yourself with the site. Thank you!

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking how to have a service load a web page (as if it was a web-client/browser) or if you're simply asking how to make a website that can be accessed from a browser.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I want to make server program which It have HTML or ASP.Net Home Page to open in web browser. It is like when we call router IP and router will open HTML page, Apache server and so on.

Comment: In that case, the most obvious solution is to creat an ASP.NET web site project. If you want something lighter weight, you could use OWIN or just roll your own HTTP server using the HttpListener class.

Comment: @StevenDoggart I can create web pages no problem I want to know how to start server to run it with IP address and Port number. When I use HTTPLISTENER then it can access other computer in local area?

Comment: Yes. HttpListener is the core .NET class that provides the ability to create an HTTP server. You tell it to start listening on a particular URL and it notifies you whenever it receives an HTTP request and allows you to send the response. It is rather low-level though. OWIN wraps it in a higher level framework so you don’t have to get as much into the nitty gritty stuff. OWIN, though, still requires you to create the host process and provide the configuration and a little plumbing. If you want to be completely hands off and let a much larger framework handle everything for you, then ASP.NET.

Comment: @StevenDoggart thank you very much for your help nobody give me a way of this.

Comment: _"nobody give me a way of this"_ - We've already tried to help you help yourself. Stack Overflow is not the place for points in the right direction, but for specific programming-related questions that you cannot find an answer to elsewhere (as I said in your case there is plenty of resources out there, just google _VB.NET Web Server_). I highly recommend you take a look at the links I shared in my previous comment and familiarize yourself with this site. If you ask questions that goes against the Stack Overflow's guidelines you can't expect to get much help.